# KendoUI Upload status message issue in IE9

Tags: kendo-ui

While using Kendo UI Upload control I am facing a UI issue that I am unable to resolve as in FF, Chrome and IE10 its fine. But, in IE9 the UI is little bit distorted when status message is displayed.

After observing in IE developer tool, I found the following difference in the rendered HTML. Please refer the image -

[image: Status Message after uploading a file in IE9 and IE10]
In IE10 the status-message is wrapped inside a div with class k-dropzone. But, in IE9 there is no wrapper for that. What could be the solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps padding div containing the file upload control will spread out the elements a little:

```
 #fileUpload {
        padding:15px,15px,0px,15px;
        clear:both;  
  }
```